# How to write in a specific cell with pandas and iterrows?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to learn how to use both excel and python. And i'm trying to found out how to write in a speicific cell with pandas. This is what i tought would work :

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name="Feuil2")

for row in raw_data.iterrows():
    print(row[1]['name'])
    row[1]['name'] = "Cassandra"
```

I very much like the fact that it's loops through the cells in a column and it would be easier doing this (i found) than using OpenPyxl and doing something like this :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filepath)
sheet = workbook.worksheets[1]

my_cell = sheet['A6']

my_cell.value = "ME"
```

What i really need help on is using the `iterrows` function and write in a cell.

Comment: u can use the loc mthod something like "df.loc[IndexRow, Column] = Value"

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Yes but what values do i put for row and Column while using iterrows() ? I don't get those coordonates with iterrows

Comment: @CharlieClark the question is how to write in a cell while using iterrows() ? Because in my first code the line where i indicate i want to write "Cassandra" in my sheet does not work

Comment: `iterrows()` is a dataframe method. Use `sheet.iter_rows(min_row=, max_row=, min_col=, max_coll=)` directly in openpyxl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because [df.itterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) yields new Series, and you're modifying those instead of your original dataframe. Additionally, your "row" is a tuple of the row index and the row object, which may be confusing you. Here's how you could do it (or  [via some of the other indexing methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)).

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, 'name'] = "Cassandra"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried something like this : `import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name="Feuil2")

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, 'name'] = "Cassandra"` . But there is no changes in my file

Comment: Did you save your changes to a (new) excel file? Making dataframe changes doesn't do much for you if it only happens inside the dataframe. Not too familiar with openpyxl, but pandas can do that too, see [this function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)